# Use macro as totcount counter name

Tags: macros, environments, counters

In the top level of the `document` environment, a macro defined (using `\def`) can be expanded into the name of a `totcount` counter. This, for some reason, does not work inside an environment definition. I tried various combinations of `\newcommand`, `\expandafter`, `\edef`, etc., none of which worked.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{totcount}

\newenvironment{passagequestions}{% This does not work
    \def\counterIDX{passagecounterX}%
    \newtotcounter{c\counterIDX}%
    \total{c\counterIDX}%
    }{%
    }

\begin{document}
    \def\counterID{passagecounter}
    \newtotcounter{c\counterID}% This works
    \total{c\counterID}

    \begin{passagequestions}
        this doesn't work
    \end{passagequestions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You should not use `\newtotcounter` in the document body

Comment: @ChristianHupfer My project involves defining an arbitrary number of `totcounter`s at compilation.

Comment: Yes, I see, but I think you should use a different strategy...

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, I think I'm smelling the X-Y condemnation; I'll go ask a new question.

Comment: No, that's not the point. You're screwing up the counter register management this way.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, can you explain?

Comment: Defining `\newtotcounter` on-the-fly during document body usage might (!) be confusing the counter register management by TeX/LaTeX. It might work, but there's no guarantee

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are doing inside an environment you need to define `\counterIDX`  "globally" by using `\gdef`:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{totcount}

\newenvironment{passagequestions}{% This does not work
    \gdef\counterIDX{passagecounterX}%
    \newtotcounter{c\counterIDX}%
    \total{c\counterIDX}%
    }{%
    }

\begin{document}
    \def\counterID{passagecounter}
    \newtotcounter{c\counterID}% This works
    \total{c\counterID}

    \begin{passagequestions}
        this doesn't work
    \end{passagequestions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: And as soon as `passagecounterX` is something more than a constant token `\xdef` would be better, I assume?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I don't now what the hard and fast rules are but usually `\gdef` is enough. It depends on how the code is being used and, you're right, sometimes `\xdef` is required.