# How can I print beginning and end values of a counter within an environment?

Tags: environments, counters

I'm working on a formatting system for standardized tests. Within each section of a test, there are groups of consecutive questions that I might choose to contain inside an environment.

```
\begin{passagequestions}
    \begin{question} % question 1, or whichever this is.
    \end{question}
    % and so on
\end{passagequestions}
```

The counter `questioncount` is provided outside whenever `passagequestions` is used. Assume that `question` does little more than increment the question number, i.e. via `\stepcounter{questioncount}`.

At the beginning of each instance of `passagequestions`, I would like to name all of the questions that are part of the question group. Each instance of `passagequestions` should begin with `Questions {0}--{1} are based on the following passage.`, where `{0}` is the index of the first question (which may or may not be 1) and `{1}` is the index of the last question.

My previous solution was going to begin by using a `totcount` to keep track of the length of a question group, but I got the impression that [that was not a good idea](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/257778/use-macro-as-totcount-counter-name/257783#257783).

Comment: How about a `\label` approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit** See the better version at the end.

Similar to Werner, but I am using fake labels, which can break as soon as `hyperref` is used.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{refcount}

\newcounter{passage}%
\newcounter{question}

\newenvironment{question}{\refstepcounter{question}}{}



\makeatletter
\newenvironment{passagequestions}{%
  \refstepcounter{passage}%
  % Store the fake label for the beginning
  \immediate\write\@auxout{%
    \string\newlabel{passagestart::\number\value{passage}}{{\number\value{question}}{\thepage}}%
  }%
  Questions \getrefnumber{passagestart::\number\value{passage}} -- \getrefnumber{passageend::\number\value{passage}} are based on the following passage.
}{%Store the fake label for the end
  \immediate\write\@auxout{%
    \string\newlabel{passageend::\number\value{passage}}{{\number\value{question}}{\thepage}}%
  }%
}
\makeatother





\begin{document}

\begin{passagequestions}
\begin{question}
\end{question}

\begin{question}
\end{question}
\begin{question}
\end{question}
\begin{question}
\end{question}


\end{passagequestions}

\begin{passagequestions}

\begin{question}
\end{question}

\begin{question}
\end{question}
\begin{question}
\end{question}
\begin{question}
\end{question}


\end{passagequestions}


\end{document}
```

**Edit** Better version

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newif\ifnewpassage
\newpassagefalse

\newcounter{passage}%
\newcounter{question}


%Define some dummy question environment

\newenvironment{question}{%
\vskip0.3\abovedisplayskip

\refstepcounter{question}%
\colorbox{yellow}{\bfseries \textcolor{blue}{Question \thequestion}}%

\addvspace{0.5\baselineskip}
}{\vskip0.5\belowdisplayskip}

% Add some code to the question environment
\makeatletter

\newcommand{\storefakelabel}[3][\number\value{passage}]{%
  \immediate\write\@auxout{%
    \string\newlabel{#2#1}{{#3}{\thepage}}%
  }%
}

\newcommand{\passagestartprefix}{passagestart:}
\newcommand{\passageendprefix}{passageend:}

\newcommand{\getstartquestion}{%
  \getrefnumber{\passagestartprefix\number\value{passage}}
}

\newcommand{\getendquestion}{%
  \getrefnumber{\passageendprefix\number\value{passage}}%
}

\xapptocmd{\question}{% Append the stuff after(!!!) the question startup code has been done!
  \ifnewpassage%
  \storefakelabel{\passagestartprefix}{\number\value{question}}%
  \global\newpassagefalse%
  \fi%
}{}{}

\newcommand{\passagequestionsheading}{%
\colorbox{green}{Questions \getstartquestion -- \getendquestion\ are based on the following passage.}
}

\newenvironment{passagequestions}{%
  \vskip\abovedisplayskip%
  \newpassagetrue% Started a new passage
  \refstepcounter{passage}%
  \colorbox{red}{\large \bfseries Questions passage \thepassage}%

  \passagequestionsheading

}{%
  % Store the fake label for the end
  \storefakelabel{\passageendprefix}{\number\value{question}}%
  \vskip\belowdisplayskip%
}
\makeatother



\begin{document}

\begin{passagequestions}
\begin{question}
  Why does \LaTeXe\ provide that much fun?
\end{question}

\begin{question}
\end{question}
\begin{question}
\end{question}
\begin{question}
\end{question}


\end{passagequestions}

\begin{passagequestions}

\begin{question}
\end{question}

\begin{question}
\end{question}
\begin{question}
\end{question}
\begin{question}
\end{question}


\end{passagequestions}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What makes the better version better?

Comment: @SimonKuang: It uses the correct question counter ranges for each `passage`, the first version just used the old one from a previous passage, but did not increment it. That was wrong

Answer (score 1):

Here is an informal solution to your question:

1. Mark the beginning and end of the `passagequestions` environment with a `\label`
2. Recall these `\label`s as `\ref`s in the start of the `passagequestions` environment.

You'll have to make sure that counter stepping survives the environment it's called in. While this is naturally the case, redefinition of the stepped counter's value in `\@currentlabel` - used with the `\label`-`\ref` system - does not.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{question}
\newcounter{passagequestions}
\newenvironment{passagequestions}
  {\stepcounter{passagequestions}%
   \par\addvspace{\bigskipamount}\noindent
   Questions \ref{pq-\thepassagequestions-start}--\ref{pq-\thepassagequestions-end} are based on the following passage\ldots
   \par
   \renewcommand{\question}{%
     \oldquestion%
     \label{pq-\thepassagequestions-start}%
     \global\let\question\oldquestion}}%
  {\label{pq-\thepassagequestions-end}}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{question}
  {\stepcounter{question}%
   \xdef\@currentlabel{\thequestion}%
   \par\addvspace{\baselineskip}%
   \textbf{Question~\thequestion}:}
  {}
\makeatother

\let\oldquestion\question

\begin{document}

\begin{passagequestions}
  This is the first passage\ldots
  \begin{question}
    First question
  \end{question}
  \begin{question}
    Second question
  \end{question}
  \begin{question}
    Third question
  \end{question}
\end{passagequestions}

\begin{passagequestions}
  This is the second passage \ldots
  \begin{question}
    First question
  \end{question}
  \begin{question}
    Second question
  \end{question}
  \begin{question}
    Third question
  \end{question}
\end{passagequestions}

\end{document}
```